# googlemobileads Packages cannot be imported Admob native ads Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, kotlin, admob

I'm trying to implement Admob native ads I followed this [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads) but when I try to `import io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin`
I have an error `Packages cannot be imported`

the Kotlin code :

// TODO: Implement ListTileNativeAdFactory class

```
package com.codelab.flutter.admobinlineads;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Map;

import io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin; //I cannot import this plugin

class ListTileNativeAdFactory implements GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.NativeAdFactory {

    private final Context context;

    ListTileNativeAdFactory(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public NativeAdView createNativeAd(
            NativeAd nativeAd, Map<String, Object> customOptions) {
        NativeAdView nativeAdView = (NativeAdView) LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.list_tile_native_ad, null);

        TextView attributionViewSmall = nativeAdView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_list_tile_native_ad_attribution_small);
        TextView attributionViewLarge = nativeAdView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_list_tile_native_ad_attribution_large);

        ImageView iconView = nativeAdView.findViewById(R.id.iv_list_tile_native_ad_icon);
        NativeAd.Image icon = nativeAd.getIcon();
        if (icon != null) {
            attributionViewSmall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            attributionViewLarge.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            iconView.setImageDrawable(icon.getDrawable());
        } else {
            attributionViewSmall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            attributionViewLarge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        nativeAdView.setIconView(iconView);

        TextView headlineView = nativeAdView.findViewById(R.id.tv_list_tile_native_ad_headline);
        headlineView.setText(nativeAd.getHeadline());
        nativeAdView.setHeadlineView(headlineView);

        TextView bodyView = nativeAdView.findViewById(R.id.tv_list_tile_native_ad_body);
        bodyView.setText(nativeAd.getBody());
        bodyView.setVisibility(nativeAd.getBody() != null ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
        nativeAdView.setBodyView(bodyView);

        nativeAdView.setNativeAd(nativeAd);

        return nativeAdView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you include code or log files!!

Comment: Done, I just copied this code here https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-inline-ads-in-flutter#7